# Migrating website to higher version of PHP

Tags: php

I have a website hosted on a VPS server using PHP version 5.6.40. I would like to upgrade PHP version to 7.0.33. Is there a way to run some sort of audit  to determine if anything would break as a result of migration?

Comment: I guess you need to have unit tests to check it and prevent errors on production. Or at least you need to configure error reporting and fix them if they appear, but in this case it's fixing post factum

Comment: You can just download the files locally and then run them on a local webserver to make sure everything's still working before you perform the upgrade.

Comment: How about reading the manual? https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.php

Answer (score -1):

The best way to determine this is to have a full suite of tests for the application in question. You can then run it on the new version.

Failing that, I have used [PHP Compatibility](https://github.com/PHPCompatibility/PHPCompatibility) before, which is a series of sniffs for PHP Codesniffer, and will at least tell you if the syntax is incompatible with the specified version of PHP. It won't guarantee it will work as expected with that version, but will catch syntax problems, which you can then resolve manually.

It still doesn't offer a cast iron guarantee that it'll catch everything, but if the application is small then coupling it with manual testing may be sufficient.